# Ubuntu 12.10 wireless reports it is working, but actually doesnt

Tags: networking

I have Ubuntu 12.10 installed with windows 7 on a partitioned hard drive in a new gateway tower. My wireless card is made by realtek. The install went fine, I was able to connect to wireless to install updates and whatnot. However, at some point both wired and wireless internet began working poorly/not at all in Ubuntu. The aggravating part is: Ubuntu claims both are working just fine and both work great in windows. At the moment I am online with an ethernet cable which the network manager says is running at 1000mbs and also have available a wireless network at 130mbs. However the connection continually goes in and out (which is not registered in the network center, i just cant open webpages, install packages or even ping external websites). At this very moment I can chat in gchat, but cannot load new pages in ask ubuntu forums or download updates. I have spent several hours in forums trying to fix this, but am otherwise a novice with linux. I tried installing a new driver for the wireless card, but am not sure it worked, as in the install report one error message: Module 8192cu does not exist in /proc/modules. No drivers appear in software sources. Any help would be tremendously appreciated.

Comment: possibly you are facing a dns error/ using slow dns server. Try changing DNS server of modem/router to `8.8.8.8`.

Comment: @Web-E please don't forget the fact that having 8.8.8.8 as standard name server (not only for testing) may have privacy implications - who wants google to know abaout every website they visit?

Comment: @guntbert I think it is better to have an working internet connection rather than nothing (if that is the case here). Regarding privacy, whatever dns you choose they can log. Who says your ISP isn't logging your activity? at least google has some [privacy policy](https://developers.google.com/speed/public-dns/privacy). Any unencrypted traffic has privacy concerns.